# Using regular expressions with xpath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use xpath to obtain xml node values that match a specific pattern (anything that has the pattern YYYY/MM/DD). In the example below, I would only want to find the 2nd item. I've tried using fn:matches and php:functionString with preg_match, to no avail.

```
<sometag>
  <link>site:www.mysite.com/2014/</link>
</sometag>
<sometag>
  <link>site:www.mysite.com/2014/01/07</link>
</sometag>
```

I thought I was on the right track here, but surprise surprise, it did not work.

```
$regex = '~(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])~';
$results = $xml->xpath("//link[php:functionString('preg_match', '".$regex."', .)]");
```

I've tried looking for just "2013" using fn:matches, this also didn't work.

```
$results = $xml->xpath("//link[fn:matches('2013')]");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind `DOMXPath` only supports XPath 1.0, for your second attempt, you can use `contains` instead of `matches`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd like to filter the `DOMNodeList` according to the return value of `preg_match`.  Here's a way to do that:

```
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
    $xpath->registerPhpFunctions();

    $list = $xpath->query("//sometag[1 = php:function('preg_match',
                '/07/', string(link))]");

    foreach ($list as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
```

In the snipped above, `$doc` refers to an instance of DOMDocument.

I am using the fact `preg_match` returns 1 if a match is found and 0 if not.

*Note*: This snippet is meant to serve as a starting point, not a final solution.